# Why use array.prototype.values() instead of for loop together with a normal array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I was reviewing Javascript array methods and came across `array.prototype.values()`. I ask myself why we want to create an iterable instead of a for loop with a regular array object?

The only reason I can think of is that it might make the code more concise, shorter and clear? Are there other use cases for representing an array as an iterator using `array.prototype.values()`?

Comment: It's a simple way to get an iterator when you're working with another API that requires one.

Comment: An iterator is stateful so they are very flexible in terms of the location in the program and the point in time that they provide the `next` value. This is often useful in asynchronous programming where you want to get the `next` value in response to some event.